# How to demonstrate that light carries angular momentum by making an object rotate?

Tags: electromagnetism, angular-momentum, home-experiment

Electromagnetic fields, carry angular momentum. However, I want to demonstrate by an experiment and convince a bunch of high school students, that electromagnetic fields do carry angular momentum. To that end, can we **design an experiment** in which the angular momentum of the electromagnetic field be transferred to a mechanical object causing it to rotate?

Comment: The EM waves contain angular momentum which is composed of spin angular momentum and orbital angular momentum. I do not see how you will be able to demonstrate that to a class and that too in a non-laboratory setting. Even demonstrating the linear momentum carried by EM radiation is difficult enough.

Comment: Electron or nuclear spin resonance... note that in incoherent lifht the angular moment randomized. On macroscopic level one can demonstrate polarization of light.

Comment: @RogerVadim How about using LASER to make something rotate?

Comment: @Mechanic I did not say "in a non-laboratory setting"! Of course in a laboratory but through an experiment that is understandable and convincing to high-school students.

Comment: How are you going to rotate the mechanical object? Is it by trying to rotate a pivoted body? That would prove that light possesses linear momentum, not angular momentum.

Comment: @Mechanic Not pivoted but allowed to rotate freely about an axis (say). Also, that object must be able to interact with the EM field appreciably. If the object rotates, by the conservation of angular momentum, it must have gained an angular momentum from that of the EM field. Of course, I don't know how to achieve that, and hence the question.

Comment: I wonder if a couple of the discussions in the Red Books (Feynman Lectures) might be helpful here!

Comment: A cool experiment is described by Sharma: https://doi.org/10.1119/1.15592

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One example can be found in *Introduction to Electrodynamics* by Griffiths, example 7.8.

Horizontally suspend a uniformly-charged insulating ring from its center (perhaps by attaching spokes from the ring to its center, and then attaching a string to the center). Place a solenoidal electromagnet directly below the center of the ring with orientation perpendicular to the plane of the ring (i.e. vertically).

Switching the electromagnet on or off will impart angular momentum to the ring and cause it to rotate, even though no mechanical torque is acting on the ring.

Comment: So, is Lenz's law the consequence of EM waves possessing angular momentum? As far as I know, it is the consequence of the conservation of energy principle.